# Trying to remove the last part of a path python

Tags: python, path, format

I have a path which is `A/B/C/D`. I am trying to remove the last part so that I end up with `A/B/C/`. I've done:

```
path = pathlib.Path(r"A/B/C/D")
path.parent
```

which gives me

```
PosixPath('A/B/C')
```

However, it has removed the forward slash after "C". Is there a similar way to do this so that it does not remove the last forward slash? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.join(path, '')` will add the trailing slash if it's not there:

```
import pathlib
import os

path = pathlib.Path(r"A/B/C/D")
print(path.parent)
print(os.path.join(path.parent, ''))
```

Output:

```
A/B/C
A/B/C/
```